# Can such an almost class $C^1$ function exist?

Tags: calculus

This might be a question with a rather basic answer but it has bothering me for a while. Consider a function $f(x)$ of class $C^1$ for $x=[a,b[$ and differentiable at $x=b$. Can $f'(x)\equiv d f(x)/dx$ be non-continuous at $x=b$?

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to b} f'(x)$ and $f'(b)$ both exist, then they agree. But as the standard example (that Teddy38 presents) shows, if $\lim_{x \to b} f'(x)$ does not exist, then $f'(b)$ can still exist and $f'$ doesn't have to be continuous at $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ as $$f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$$ 
for $x\in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. Calculate its (right) derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: =D such a nice example. Thank you